# Angular 2 subscribe after tab change and revisit

Tags: angular, service, observable

I have a Subject service like this;

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();

sendMessage(message: any) {
    this.subject.next(message);
}

clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next();
}

getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

And feeding the message from parent component

**NOTE: My parent-child components connected via `router-outlet`**

```
private getMerchantDetail() {
let data = {
  Id: this.merchantId,
}
this.merchantsService.getMerchants(data)
  .then((res) => {
    // console.log(res)
    if (res.Success) {
      this.merchant = res.Data[0];
      this.merchantListDetailService.sendMessage(res.Data[0]); -> here
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => { })
}
```

And then subscribing the data from all child components;

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.merchantSubscribe = this.merchantListDetailService.getMessage()
      .subscribe(merchant => {
        console.log(merchant)
        this.merchant = merchant;
        this.getMerchantPaymentChannels();
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.merchantSubscribe.unsubscribe();
  }
```

PROBLEM: 
Everything is good when one of child components initially opened on reloaded page. But when I changed the tab of my child components, and revisit the initially opened child component again, it doesnt get the subscribed data. But `ngOnInit` function works again. Also `getMessage() in service` also works. Only child component subscribe callback doesn't get the data again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat old question but I came across the same issue. What I did to resolve this was by using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject. My understanding is that BehaviorSubject will "remember" the previously set value but Subject won't.

When you subscribe to a Subject, it's only listening for changes but if there aren't any then nothing will happen. When the parent sets the next value for the Subject, it will send out the message but doesn't retain any information about what it sent out. And since you're just using tabs, that parent is sending it once and that's it. Your child gets the first "change" but since nothing changes for the parent when you change tabs, it won't send another message.

There's a very strong possibility that I misunderstood how all that works but the only real difference that I had to do when I went from Subject to BehaviorSubject was set an initial value for the BehaviorSubject.

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubjectSubject<any>('');

sendMessage(message: any) {
    this.subject.next(message);
}

clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next('');
}

getMessage(): BehaviorSubject<any> {
    return this.subject;
}
```

Also, I changed the return type to BehaviorSubject and removed the asObservable.

When the child is initialized it will have a blank value (or whatever you set that initial BehaviorSubject to) but when the parent sets the next value, it will pick up the change and that BehaviorSubject will retain the value as well. So when you change tabs, no matter how many times it will go back to that value.

I don't know if there are cons that come to doing it this way but it seems to be working well for me now. I will update if that changes or if I find out a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need a function within your child component which calls the getMessage in service as well or you need to pass the message or data which you got from parent component via @Input decorator